# How to interpret camera.yml of object_recognition_transparent_object?

Tags: ros, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to use [transparent_object](http://wg-perception.github.io/transparent_objects/index.html#transparent-objects) to estimate the pose of my object. And the sample program needs camera.yml as input.

```
%YAML:1.0
camera:
   K: !!opencv-matrix
      rows: 3
      cols: 3
      dt: d
      data: [ 525., 0., 3.2050000000000000e+02, 0., 525.,
          2.4050000000000000e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
   D: !!opencv-matrix
      rows: 5
      cols: 1
      dt: f
      data: [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. ]
   width: 640 
   height: 480 
   pose:
      rvec: !!opencv-matrix
         rows: 3
         cols: 1
         dt: d
         data: [ 0., 0., 0. ]
      tvec: !!opencv-matrix
         rows: 3
         cols: 1
         dt: d
         data: [ 0., 0., 0. ]
```

I've found that this file is for camera calibration,
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html
http://maztories.blogspot.tw/2013/07/camera-calibration-with-opencv.html

I don't know the relationship between this file and PR2. If I want to use PR2's kinect to get image, do I need to adjust the content of this file? How do I adjust it?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192774/how-to-interpret-camera.yml-of-object_recognition_transparent_object?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, the K matrix is the intrinsic matrix. D is the distortion coefficients. And this is not related to PR2's tf.
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

If I want to modify this file, I can use [camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration) to get results and use [camera calibration parser](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration_parsers) to transform the format.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0